# How to return an &str when strings are dynamically generated?

Tags: rust

I have the following error code for VM:

```
/// These are the different types of errors which stepping through a VM can produce.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum VmErrorType {
    UnknownOpCode(i8),
    UnknownVariable(char),
    IllegalVariableName(i8),
    IllegalJump(i8, usize, usize),
    StackEmpty,
    UnexpectedEndOfBytecode,
}

/// VmError encapsulates the VmErrorType and adds the common offset of where the error was found.
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub struct VmError { // public so that errors can be interrogated
    subtype: VmErrorType, // "type" is a reserved keyword
    offset: usize,
}

impl fmt::Display for VmError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> Result<(), fmt::Error> {
        let message = match self.subtype {
            VmErrorType::UnknownOpCode(opcode) => format!("unknown opcode ({opcode})"),
            VmErrorType::UnknownVariable(varname) => format!("unknown variable ({varname})"),
            VmErrorType::IllegalVariableName(varname) => format!("illegal variable name ({varname})"),
            VmErrorType::IllegalJump(delta, src, dst) => format!("illegal jump of {delta} from {src} to {dst}"),
            VmErrorType::StackEmpty => "empty stack".to_string(),
            VmErrorType::UnexpectedEndOfBytecode => "unexpected end of bytecode".to_string(),
        };
        write!(f, "{} at offset {}", message, self.offset)
    }
}

impl error::Error for VmError {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        "VmError" // FIXME: this could do with being more specific, but we have lifetime issues here
    }
}
```

How can I return a `description()` as an `&str` when they are dynamically generated?

Is there a better way of structuring multiple error cases where some properties are error-specific while others (`offset`) apply to all?

Comment: Are you using `std::error::Error`? If yes, why do you want to implement `description` at all? It has the default implementation, and is deprecated anyway.

Comment: `description()` *can't* be more specific for types like yours, which is presumably why it was deprecated. Just leave the default implementation.

Comment: If I understand correctly `&str` can only be returned if you wrap that function in a `static` lifetime. But then you could only return string literals that you have already hard-coded. If  you want to return useful and specific diagnostic information you want to return a `String`. That `String` can then be referenced in the caller as a string slice `&str` if they want to. You cannot return a non-static, allocated `String` as `&str`.

Comment: @MYZ *If I understand correctly `&str` can only be returned if you wrap that function in a static lifetime* - It's not limited to static strings, but to strings that live at least as long as the error value. This obviously includes `&'satic str`, but it also allows returning slices of a `String` value owned by the error. In either case, note that the signature of the function is given by the trait, so the OP cannot change it. (But they can elect not to implement the method, which is obsolete and has a default implementation.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This a know deficiency of `Error::description()`, which is why [it is deprecated](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html#method.description) and you should not use it.

Instead, implement `std::fmt::Display` for your error type. Do not bother implementing `description`; pretend it's not there.